# Store and retrieve user roles

Tags: vue.js

I'm relative new to Vue.js. Our application needs to restrict / secure access to specific pages based on user role(s) and consequently also display just the respective item in the menu.

I would like to understand what's the recommended approach to store the user role information and retrieve where  necessary to take these decisions.

I searched around and landed in pages about Vuex Store, maybe storing in the Session Storage, or even libraries like CASL, but if any, I got even more confused.

I would appreciate any feedback from experienced Vue developers.

Comment: You need a state management library to store user information in a centralized fashion. One of the most popular for Vue is Vuex. Session Storage may or may not be used, It really depends on your authentication logic.

Comment: Auth is checked in Vue Router beforeEnter. You may NOT need state management libarary, but you need global state any way, which can be simply implemented in Vue. And Vuex is a safe default for global state.

Comment: If you don't want to re-invent the wheel, you can use a library such as https://github.com/websanova/vue-auth .

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to store user data in the dedicated Vuex module state (say's "account") and create getters to get computed values, one of which will be, say's `isAuthenticated`. The most common way to check if a user is authenticated is just to get the state value (because the default value should be `null`).

```
state: {
  account: null
},

actions: { // Here we will fill the account state },

getters: {
  isAuthenticated (state) {
    return Boolean(state.account);
  }
}
```

P.S. - In special cases, user data could be stored in LocalStorage, SessionStorage, Cookies, etc., in which case you can still get access to this data through Vuex still. But basically, we only store tokens in these stores.